# Filter df if more than two unique values - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df that contains values at various time points. I have two separate columns which should display a single set of unique values for each time point. This occurs for the most part but sometimes time points contain multiple unique values. I'm hoping to filter these using conditional logic.

For the df below, there are unique time points in `Time`. I only want to have one set of unique values for `Value` and `Object` for each time point. If two unique items occur in `Value` I want to drop `X` and keep `Y`, regardless of what is in `Object`. If there are two unique items in `Object` then I want to keep the first row. In this instance, the items will be the same in `Value`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({   
        'Time' : ['2019-08-02 09:50:10.1','2019-08-02 09:50:10.1','2019-08-02 09:50:10.2','2019-08-02 09:50:10.2','2019-08-02 09:50:10.3','2019-08-02 09:50:10.3','2019-08-02 09:50:10.4','2019-08-02 09:50:10.4','2019-08-02 09:50:10.6','2019-08-02 09:50:10.6'],
        'Object' : ['A','A','B','B','C','A','C','B','B','B'],                 
        'Value' : ['X','X',np.nan,np.nan,'Y','X','Y','Y','Z','Z'],                  
        })
```

I initially considered returning the rows that contain more than one unique set of items at each time point, which could be used for filtering.

```
unq_Object = df.groupby('Time').apply(lambda x: x['Object'].unique())
unq_Value = df.groupby('Time').apply(lambda x: x['Value'].unique())
```

But I'm not sure if there is a more efficient method?

Intended output:

```
                    Time Object Value
0  2019-08-02 09:50:10.1      A     X
1  2019-08-02 09:50:10.1      A     X
2  2019-08-02 09:50:10.2      B   NaN
3  2019-08-02 09:50:10.2      B   NaN
4  2019-08-02 09:50:10.3      C     Y
5  2019-08-02 09:50:10.4      C     Y
6  2019-08-02 09:50:10.6      B     Z
7  2019-08-02 09:50:10.6      B     Z
```

Comment: I'm confused by your intended output. I'm printing your DataFrame and appear to be getting just that.

Comment: The sample df has 10 rows, my output has 8?

Comment: Nevermind me then ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update use `duplicate`

```
df[df.duplicated(keep=False)|df.index.isin(df.groupby('Time').head(1).index)]
Out[187]: 
                    Time Object Value
0  2019-08-02 09:50:10.1      A     X
1  2019-08-02 09:50:10.1      A     X
2  2019-08-02 09:50:10.2      B   NaN
3  2019-08-02 09:50:10.2      B   NaN
4  2019-08-02 09:50:10.3      C     Y
6  2019-08-02 09:50:10.4      C     Y
8  2019-08-02 09:50:10.6      B     Z
9  2019-08-02 09:50:10.6      B     Z
```

If all Time have more than one

we can do

```
df[df.Time.duplicated()|df.duplicated(keep=False)]
```

Comment: i've included some more info

Comment: Thanks @WeNYoBen, this works well for duplicate values in `Object`. But duplicates in `Value` may not work. If `Y` is sorted before `X` its fine but if it's sorted after `X` it will remove it.